# Счётчик при парсинге в puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Есть функция, в которой перебирается массив ссылок:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
let links = ["https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198142264901/440/2?l=english&count=5000", "https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198296942562/440/2?l=english&count=5000", "https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198142264901/440/2?l=english&count=5000"];

async function browse() {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 100, devtools: false });
    for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        let link = links[i];
            try {
                let page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.setViewport({ width: 1400, height: 900 });
                await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
                await page.waitForSelector('body');
                async function repeater() {
                    let html = await page.evaluate(async () =>{                                               
                        let skinname = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;
                        skinname = JSON.parse(skinname)
                        let number = 0;
                        for (var i = 0; i < skinname.descriptions.length; i++) {
                            if ((skinname.descriptions[i].market_name === "The DethKapp")) {
                                for (var j = 0; j < skinname.descriptions[i].descriptions.length; j++) {
                                    if (skinname.descriptions[i].descriptions[j].value === "Paint Color: Muskelmannbraun") {
                                        ++number;                                 
                                    }
                                }
                            }                           
                        }        
                    })             
                } 
                setInterval(repeater, 1000); 
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }      
    }

}
browse();
```

как сделать так, чтобы счётчик считал совпадения на каждой странице, передавал их в определенную переменную и в итоге выводилась сумма всех совпадений, после чего счетчик бы обнулялся и цикл проходил снова?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как ваш вопрос соотносится с фрагментом кода. Функция запускается с интервалом на одной странице или на разных? Если в функции обрабатывается JSON, то при чём здесь ссылки? С чем ищутся совпадения? Скорее всего, вам стоит добавить больше контекста. Описать, что делает ваш скрипт, возможно, увеличить количество кода.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty контекст есть в предыдущем вопросе автора, но минимальный воспроизводимый пример всё равно не построить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная причина почему у вас не получается сделать требуемое - неприменение "Принципа единственной ответственности". Ваш код делает всё и сразу и поэтому с ним тяжело работать.

Предлагаю решать задачу упрощая код.

**Первое** - вынесем обработчик отдельной ссылки в отдельную функцию. Избавимся от поиска совпадений внутри контекста запущенного браузера. Сделаем так: браузер нашёл нужные данные и вернул их.

```
async function loadData(link) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1400, height: 900 });
  await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
  await page.waitForSelector('body');

  const pageData = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const data = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;
    try {
      return JSON.parse(data)?.descriptions;
    } catch (err) { /* */ }
  });

  await page.close();

  return pageData;
}
```

**Второе** - функция, обрабатывающая данные. Для каждого адреса собрала данные из первой функции и посчитала количество совпадений.

```
async function findMatches() {
  const items = await Promise.allSettled(
    links.map(loadData)
  );

  const matchesCount = items.reduce(
    (acc, x) => {
      if (x.status === 'rejected') {
        console.error(x.reason);
        return acc;
      }

      (x.value || []).forEach((item) => {
        if (isInterested(item)) {
          acc += 1;
        }
      });
      return acc;
    },
    0
  );
  return matchesCount;
}
```

Отдельно вынесем **принятие решения** - интересный или не интересный объект:

```
function isInterested(item) {
  return item.market_name === 'The DethKapp'
    && item.descriptions.some(({ value }) => value === 'Paint Color: Muskelmannbraun');
}
```

**Третье** - всё написанное завернём в пускач и бесконечное повторение.

Et voila, всё вместе:

```
/* global document */
const { setTimeout } = require('timers/promises');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const links = [
  'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198142264901/440/2?l=english&count=5000',
  'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198296942562/440/2?l=english&count=5000',
  'https://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198142264901/440/2?l=english&count=5000',
];

/** @type {puppeteer.Browser} */
let browser;

(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
  });

  do {
    const matchesCount = await findMatches();
    console.log(`[${new Date().toISOString()}] ${matchesCount}`);
    await setTimeout(2000);
  } while (1);

  await browser.close();
})();

/**
 * @returns {Promise<number>}
 */
async function findMatches() {
  const items = await Promise.allSettled(
    links.map(loadData)
  );

  const matchesCount = items.reduce(
    (acc, x) => {
      if (x.status === 'rejected') {
        console.error(x.reason);
        return acc;
      }

      (x.value || []).forEach((item) => {
        if (isInterested(item)) {
          acc += 1;
        }
      });
      return acc;
    },
    0
  );
  return matchesCount;
}

/**
 * @param {Record<string, any>} item
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function isInterested(item) {
  return item.market_name === 'The DethKapp'
    && item.descriptions?.some(({ value }) => value === 'Paint Color: Muskelmannbraun');
}

/**
 * @param {string} link
 * @returns {Promise<Array<Record<string, any>>>}
 */
async function loadData(link) {
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1400, height: 900 });
  await page.goto(link, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
  await page.waitForSelector('body');

  const pageData = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const data = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;
    try {
      return JSON.parse(data)?.descriptions;
    } catch (err) { /* */ }
  });

  await page.close();

  return pageData;
}
```

В консоли:

```bsh
~/git/stackoverflow-practice $ node src/puppeteer-steamcommunity/index.js 
[2021-05-23T18:26:22.015Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:26:29.736Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:26:36.884Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:26:44.980Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:26:53.520Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:00.185Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:06.270Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:13.507Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:21.307Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:28.601Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:36.115Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:44.886Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:27:53.841Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:28:01.060Z] 2
[2021-05-23T18:28:09.044Z] 2
```

<sub>nodejs v16.2.0, puppeteer v9.1.1</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю ситуацию, попробуйте так: возвращайте счётчик из функции, исполняемой в `page.evaluate()` и выводите его. Чтобы не путались страницы, можно выводить ещё какой-то идентификатор страницы при этом (например, номер адреса из массива или сам адрес).

```js
async function repeater(number) {
    const count = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let skinname = document.querySelector('pre').textContent;
        skinname = JSON.parse(skinname)
        let number = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < skinname.descriptions.length; i++) {
            if ((skinname.descriptions[i].market_name === "The DethKapp")) {
                for (var j = 0; j < skinname.descriptions[i].descriptions.length; j++) {
                    if (skinname.descriptions[i].descriptions[j].value === "Paint Color: Muskelmannbraun") {
                        ++number;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return number;
    });
    console.log(count);
}
setInterval(repeater, 1000);
```