# Постоянно работающий скрипт на NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Заранее прощу прощения если вопрос примитивный. Я новичок в Node Js.

У меня есть задача, сделать скрипт который будет открывать определенные ссылки и отправлять HTML страницы на сервер.

Скрипт должен выполнять эти действия тогда когда это нужно.

Как я вижу реализацию этого проекта:

1. Для получения HTML я буду использовать [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)
2. Теперь мне нужно чтобы скрипт понимал когда нужно заходить на страницу и на какую.

Если бы я делал это например в браузере (через userscript), я бы сделал через **setInterval** , чтобы раз в 10 секунд шел запрос на мой php скрипт, который возвращал бы что-то типа: `[url: https://example.com, id: 5]` а если покуда не нужно идти по URL, то приходил бы пустой массив.

И как только userscript получил url и id, он бы запомнил этот id, при этом остановил бы выполнение setInterval (*clearInterval()*)  перешел бы на URL, получил html страницы и отправил бы POST запрос на мой php скрипт, в котором бы передал id и html страницы полученной по url. Далее возобновил бы работу *setInterval*.

И нужно чтобы этот скрипт постоянно был в работе.

Как реализовать подобное? Мне бы какой-то хотя бы минимально воспроизводимый пример. Наверное сейчас моя проблема в том что я не очень понимаю как организовывать работы в скрипте Node Js.
плюс ко всему (скорее минус) в том что свои знания в JavaScript я оцениваю где-то на 5 из 10.

Comment: по тегу puppeteer навалом «воспроизводимых примеров»

Comment: вот тут, например, сделаны 80% вашей задачи https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1285376/2659